# How to attach an interface to an instance with the openstack client?

Tags: openstack

According to the OpenStack docs the individual clients are deprecated in favor for the openstack client.

> The following individual clients are deprecated in favor of a common client. ([source](http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/common/cli-install-openstack-command-line-clients.html))

So I started using the openstack client. With the `nova` client, I could attach interfaces to instances after their creation with `nova interface-attach --port-id $PID <Nova instance name>`. I wonder how this is possible with the openstack client?

There is `port set --device-owner` and `port set --device`, but they doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: did you figure out a way to do this?

Comment: @frei: No progress on this unfortunately.

Comment: yeah it seems like i'll have to keep using nova for this for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also wanted to do this and eventually found `openstack server add port $SERVERNAME $PORTUUID` works with latest python-openstack.  See [here](https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/latest/cli/command-objects/server.html#server-add-port) for documentation.

But I really just wanted to do this during instance creation and discovered you can also add multiple interfaces with specified IP addresses using the [`--nic`](https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/latest/cli/command-objects/server.html#cmdoption-openstack-server-create-nic) option to server create, like: `openstack server create --network Net1 --nic net-id=$NET2_UUID,v4-fixed-ip=$IPADDRESS ...`.

Hope this helps someone else from doing the same research.